# What is the best data structure to represent arbitrary hierarchical data?

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, hdf5, h5py

What would the best data structure to represent/read in hierarchical data (such as a folder/file layout) that has arbitrary amounts of children? I have seen N-ary trees and tries, k/d-ary heap etc... However it seems like you need to at least know the maximum amount of children per node to have in each of these structures. However, is there any sort of structure that can represent any hierarchical data without knowing anything about it other than the fact it is hierarchical in some way? I am not worrying so much about optimizing to perform so well, as I do not think I would need to deal large amounts of data (if it can be optimized then great), the important aspect is to be able to read in some random hierarchical data and maintain the organization of said data.

```
#example data

root
   - group1
      - subgroup1
         - child
         - child
             - data
      - subgroup2
      - subgroup3
         - child
             - data
   - group2
      - subgroup1
   - group3
      - subgroup1
         - child
             - data
      - subgroup2
         - child
             - data
   - group4
      - subgroup1
      - subgroup2
      - subgroup3
      - subgroup4
```

Again, format could be arbitrary, there may be anywhere from 0-500 groups, each with some arbitrary amount of nested children/paths...

Regarding context if more information is needed:

I would like to be able to read in the layout of any h5 file without having to code specifically for the h5 file or strictly organize every h5 file with the same layout. This is so I can create a GUI in which the user can navigate the h5 file (I am working with scientists who aren't as familiar with programming and would like to automate/have GUIs as much as possible). I have looked at h5py and pandas, but getting the keys via these libraries do not sort/return them in an easy to use way for representing the file layout (pandas returns leaf nodes of h5 file layout, h5py reads in each hierarchy level and you need to know the keys beforehand so it is difficult to traverse and organize the file layout). As of now, I am able to parse the keys, groups and subgroups etc... from the h5 file with these libraries but I am not able to maintain the paths. Using nested tuples seems too complicated and confusing for this purpose, which is why I was wondering about other more complex data structures.

Also, I need to do this in Python as it is the only language my colleagues work with and they do not want to learn other languages (not out of ignorance, they just are not programmers...).

Comment: Use dictionaries to map names to values, lists for homogeneous collections.

Comment: dictionaries for hierchical data

Comment: You have some misconceptions about HDF5. The schema is designed to be self-describing -- you **do not** need to know the keys (group and dataset names) in advance. And, h5py and PyTables both have tools to recursively walk the data structure to get all Groups and Dataset names. Checkout `.visititems()` method in hpy and `.walk_nodes()` method in PyTables.  I prefer `.walk_nodes()`, becuase it is a method on an object. `.visititems()` is trickier -- there are also posts in SO with examples.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate what I mean about self-describing, here is a *very simple example* that uses `.visititems()` to recursively visit every HDF5 object in the hierarchy. Modify to reference your file in the `h5py.File()` call, and you can see the output. You will get 2 lists with group and dataset names you can use to populate a GUI.

Note: `.visititems()` recursion ends if you return a value. If you want to iterate over the schema in the `main()` routine, you will need to create a generator and yield names as you go.

```
def get_h5_grps_dsets(name, h5_obj):
    
    if isinstance(h5_obj,h5py.Group):
        #print(name,'is a Group')
        grp_list.append(name)
    elif isinstance(h5_obj,h5py.Dataset):
        #print(name,'is a Dataset')
        ds_list.append(name)

with h5py.File(file_path, 'r') as h5r:
    
    grp_list = []
    ds_list = []    
    
    h5r.visititems(get_h5_grps_dsets)
    print('\nGroups:')
    for grp in grp_list:
        print(grp)
    print('\nDatasets:')
    for ds in ds_list:
        print(ds)
```